# How to write a search query in the below condition

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, where-in

I have a table named `ad_categories` and its structure is like this
[image]

And i have another table named `pub_categories` and its structure is like this
[image]

id in both table are different I need to select `id's of ad_categories` WHERE any of the `ad_categories.cid  should be in pub_categories.cid OR any of ad_categories.scid should be in ad_categories.scid OR any of the ad_categories.tcid should be in pub_categories.tcid`
i have cid list up to 35 ,scid up to 250 and tcid up to 600. How can achieve this any one please help me..

cid is main category scid is sub category and tcid is thrid subcategory. ad_category is where advertisers select categories and pub_catogries is publisher selecting categories. i have categories up to 30 subcatrgires up to 250 and thrid categories up to 600.
both advertisers and publishers can select multiple categories
i have tried by exploding pub_categories cid, scid and tcid by ',` and using like condition searching for the value like this

```
(ad_cat.cid LIKE '%,1,%' OR ad_cat.cid LIKE '%,1') OR (ad_cat.cid LIKE '%,2,%' OR ad_cat.cid LIKE '%,2')  OR (ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,1,%' OR ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,1') OR (ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,2,%' OR ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,2') OR (ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,3,%' OR ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,3') OR (ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,4,%' OR ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,4') OR (ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,5,%' OR ad_cat.scid LIKE '%,5')   OR (ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,1,%' OR ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,1') OR (ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,2,%' OR ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,2') OR (ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,3,%' OR ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,3') OR (ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,4,%' OR ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,4') OR (ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,5,%' OR ad_cat.tcid LIKE '%,5')
```

Comment: This is going to be extremely difficult to work with.  Don't store lists in `cid`, `scid`, and `tcid` -- use another table.  See [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matching comma separated with comma separated columns, you have only one choice to have a RegExp in your query. Rule is like:

```
ad_categories.cid REGEXP '(^|,)(11|2|4)(,|$)'
```

or

```
ad_categories.cid REGEXP '(^|,)(REPLACE(pub_categories.cid, ',', '|'))(,|$)'
```

Hope this will help.